# Real-time D3 timeseries using Backbone -- graph moves slower than axis

Tags: backbone.js, d3.js

I'm trying to build a real-time timeseries with D3 and Backbone. The problem I'm having is that the graph moves slower than the x-axis. The x-axis is keeping up with the current time accurately, so I know it's an issue with the graphed line. I'm basing the code off of [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) example by Mike Bostock (the last graph at the bottom of the post). I can't seem to find the problem -- my code follows the example closely, just implemented with Backbone.

The app is set up with a websocket and event aggregator so that when a new data point is received, a model of the data point is added to a collection, and adding a model triggers the function "newPoint" within the "TimeseriesView" view. "newPoint" pushes a number to an array, "data", and this is where the data for the graphed line comes from. Here is the relevant view. (Please excuse the code if it's a bit messy -- I'm new to Backbone, so I suspect there's a cleaner way to do this)

```
TimeseriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#timeseries",
    initialize: function (options) {
        var self = this;
        /*
         * Create timeseries
         */
        self.n = 243;
        self.duration = 750;
        self.now = new Date(Date.now() - self.duration);
        self.data = d3.range(self.n).map(function() { return 0; });

        self.margin = { top: 6, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 40};
        self.width = 960 - self.margin.right;
        self.height = 120 - self.margin.top - self.margin.bottom;

        self.x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([self.now - (self.n-2) * self.duration, self.now - self.duration])
            .range([0, self.width]);

        self.y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([self.height, 0]);

        var x = self.x;
        var y = self.y;
        var now = self.now;
        var duration = self.duration;
        var n = self.n;
        var height = self.height;
        var width = self.width;
        var margin = self.margin;

        self.line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
            .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

        var timeseries = d3.select("#timeseries").append("p").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        timeseries.append("defs").append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
          .append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        self.x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

        self.axis = timeseries.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(x.axis);


        self.path = timeseries.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
          .append("path")
            .data([self.data])
            .attr("class", "line");

        self.dataSet = options.dataSet;
        self.dataSet.on('add', this.newPoint, this);
    },
    newPoint: function (pt, context) {
        var self = this;
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(pt.attributes.auth_amt))) return;
        self.data.push(parseFloat(pt.attributes.auth_amt));

        self.now = new Date();

        var now = self.now;
        var duration = self.duration;
        var n = self.n;
        var x = self.x;
        var y = self.y;
        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height;
        console.log('self', self);
        x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

        // update the domains
        self.x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration,
                now - duration]);
        self.y.domain([0, d3.max(self.data)]); 

        self.line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d, i) {
                return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
            .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

        // redraw the line
        d3.select(".line")
            .attr("d", self.line)
            .attr("transform", null);

        // slide the x-axis to the left
        self.axis.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease("linear")
            .call(x.axis);

        self.x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([now - (n-2) * duration, now - duration])
            .range([0, width]);

        var x = self.x;

        // slide the line left
        self.path.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" +  x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")");

        // pop the old dat point off the front
        self.data.shift();
    }
});
```

Comment: I notice in your code this part: self.x = d3.time.scale()            .domain([now - (n-2) * duration, now - duration])            .range([0, width]);  Is moved into the update section, whereas in the example it's part of the setup. Could this be causing the axis to update faster than the data?

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it. Thanks for the suggestion, though

Answer (score 1):

The example you based your code upon deeply intertwines sliding  the x-axis and adding data. It works fine when you poll something as in the example, not so much with data arriving on a different interval or at random like I suppose it does in your websocket setup (see http://jsfiddle.net/K8rub/1/ for an hopefully accurate reproduction of your code)

The first thing to do is to separate the sliding (the `tick` function) and the data injection: http://jsfiddle.net/K8rub/2/ : each datum has a timestamp which is used to extract the x value, the data is initially empty and `tick` only slides the graph.

Applying these modifications to your code, we get

```
TimeseriesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'tick');

       // ...

        self.dataSet = options.dataSet;
        self.dataSet.on('add', this.newPoint, this);
        self.tick();
    },

    newPoint: function(model) {
        this.data.push(model);
    },

    tick: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.now = new Date();

        var now = self.now;
        var duration = self.duration;
        var n = self.n;
        var x = self.x;
        var y = self.y;
        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height;

        x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

        // update the domains
        self.x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration,
                now - duration]);
        self.y.domain([0, d3.max(self.dataSet.pluck('auth_amt'))]); 


        self.line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.get('stamp')); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.get('auth_amt')); });

        // redraw the line
        d3.select(".line")
            .attr("d", self.line)
            .attr("transform", null);

        // slide the x-axis to the left
        self.axis.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease("linear")
            .call(x.axis);

        self.x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([now - (n-2) * duration, now - duration])
            .range([0, width]);

        var x = self.x;

        // slide the line left
        self.path.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" +  x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")")
            .each("end", self.tick);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K8rub/4/